# How do you connect to the Evernote API in Haskell (with httpClient and BinaryProtocol)?

Tags: haskell, binary, thrift, network-protocols, evernote

I am trying to implement an Evernote Sync client in Haskell. For initial testing I want to connect to the Userstore with a developer authentication token. My code below causes the exception:
`ProtocolExn PE_BAD_VERSION "Missing version identifier"`

```
import Thrift.Transport.HttpClient
import Thrift.Protocol.Binary
import Network.URI
import Data.Text.Lazy
import System.Exit
import UserStore_Client
import UserStore_Consts

-- hardcoded parameters to establish test connnection
auth_token = -- developer-token-for-my-sandbox-account
user_endpoint = "https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/user"

main :: IO()
main = do
  -- parse url and open thrift http_client
  let uri = parseURI user_endpoint
  http_client <- case uri of
                    (Nothing)         -> die "Not a valid uri"
                    (Just uri_string) -> do http_cl <- (openHttpClient uri_string)
                                            return http_cl
  -- create a binary protocol that will be passed to store methods
  let user_prot = BinaryProtocol http_client

  -- try to use protocol to call a user_store method
  version_ok <- checkVersion (user_prot, user_prot) (pack auth_token) eDAM_VERSION_MAJOR eDAM_VERSION_MINOR
```

I assume that it is being thrown in the readMessage function in the implementation of BinaryProtocol. Excerpt from Thrift.Protocol.Binary:

```
readMessage p = (readMessageBegin p >>=)
      where
        readMessageBegin p = runParser p $ do
          TI32 ver <- parseBinaryValue T_I32
          if ver .&. versionMask /= version1
            then throw $ ProtocolExn PE_BAD_VERSION "Missing version identifier" -- This is the error I get
            else do
              TString s <- parseBinaryValue T_STRING
              TI32 sz <- parseBinaryValue T_I32
              return (decodeUtf8 s, toEnum $ fromIntegral $ ver .&. 0xFF, sz)

    writeVal p = tWrite (getTransport p) . toLazyByteString . buildBinaryValue
    readVal p = runParser p . parseBinaryValue
```

Do I need to configure the BinaryProtocol in a different way? Or can this be due to a version difference/datatype mismatch etc between server and client?

The UserStore module is auto-generated by Thrift (version 0.13.0) from Evernote's Thrift files.

Any leads on how I can further debug my code to understand what is going wrong would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because the server returns a 403 error. This is due to the HttpClient connecting to port 80 by default.